# SubSonic LInq IRepository

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

Trying to use SubSonic 3.0.0.4's Linq TEmplates.  Got everything working.  But in the Doc's I'm seeing how I can use aa IRepository to bulk insert, update, delete my db.  Thing is - It wasn't included in the download.  Is it somewhere else and I simply overlooked it?

I've got a ton of updates going from one "Save" call - so this would be very helpful!

Thanks

Comment: is it just us two, or doesn't it seem like all the info out there on the LinqTemplates - or AdvancedTemplates (think that's the pre-release name) - doesn't match up to the 3.0.0.4 release?

Comment: I found it implemented in the DLL itself, and I've edited the docs wiki to reflect that: http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Linq_IRepository

Answer (score 0):

IRepository is implemented in the SubSonic.Core dll.  It's in the namespace SubSonic.Repository.  There is also an implementation, SubSonicRepository.